# C function does not return the correct array size

Tags: arrays, c

I defined a function in C as below:

```
int *face_2_cells(int boundary_field_id) {
int b_cells_field[4];
if(boundary_field_id==1)
{
  b_cells_field[0]=1;
  b_cells_field[1]=2;
  b_cells_field[2]=3;
  b_cells_field[3]=4;
}
else{
  b_cells_field[0]=0;
  b_cells_field[1]=0;
  b_cells_field[2]=0;
  b_cells_field[3]=0;
}
return b_cells_field;
}
```

Then I called this function in another function and then printed the size of the array like below:

```
void
cs_user_extra_operations()
{
  {                                                                                                                               
    int *face_22_cells = face_2_cells(1);
    printf("\n SIZE = %i""  ", sizeof(face_22_cells)/sizeof(face_22_cells[0]));
}
}
```

But the code outputs the SIZE = 2, while the correct value for SIZE is 4.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Also your function returns a pointer to an array that no longer exists, so on top of the previous duplicate your code is also broken

Comment: sizeof(face_22_cells) returns the size of the pointer, not the size of what it is pointing to. So if you have a 64 bit pointer (size 8) and / sizeof(int) (4) you get 2.

Comment: Another problem you have here (unrelated to the question) is that you return a reference to the local array which stops to exist when you exit the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof` returns the size of the element you give it, which in case of `face_22_cells`, which is a pointer, is 8 bytes (64bit architecture). The size of an `int` on most architectures is 4 bytes (32bit).

So your code always evaluates to `8/4 = 2`

I think you are confusing this with calculating the length when using `sizeof` on statically declared arrays like this:

```
int array[32];
int length_of_array = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);
```

But remember, even though arrays <strike>are</strike> pointers, pointers are not arrays (if you want to be pedantic [Arrays are Not Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer/18036788#18036788)) .

While `sizeof(array)` would be `32*4 = 128`, `sizeof(int*)` is always 8 (on 64bit machines)

Comment: Thank you. But when I want to print one of pointers values as: printf("\n face2 = %i""  ", face_22_cells[0]); I get SIGSEGV signal error!

Comment: ...or `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);`

Comment: [Arrays are not pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer)

Comment: The more important problem with your code is that you are returning a pointer to a local array. When you call the `face_2_cells` function, it allocates an array `b_cells_field` on the stack and returns a pointer to it. However once it returns, the stack is popped and the pointer becomes invalid... You can never return a pointer to a local array unless its static! Either allocate it dynamically using `malloc` and `free` later or provide the buffer as an input argument to your function.